# Receiving packets on network interface generated by same machine

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I am developing some kind of "virtual server" in C on Ubuntu, that could interact with other local applications on network interface(eth,wlan). For example: Load some webpages with browser without actual internet/network connection. This "virtual server" should respond on all generated requests(ARP,DNS,TCPSYN,HTTP...) such that browser thinks that he gets data from network.

For sending packets I use raw sockets, but the problem is that they are ignored by kernel, as they are actually outgoing traffic. Is there a way I can make this kind of communication work? For example by forcing kernel to read also from outgoing traffic or send packets in such way that they appear as incoming?

I tried sending packets to loopback interface, but it didn't help. I also tried disabling some network restrictions like this:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: I would rather use an `iptables`  based approach

Comment: What exactly is your use case?

Comment: My use case is my master thesis, which is "Transmission of IP services over DVB-T for Android". So far I have made work DVB-T on Anroid, and I can transmit encapsulated IP packets. Now I need something to make it viable, so I thought opening a webpage without internet connection should do the trick. However I haven't anticipated this problem.